# Delay on DC-DC regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

Circuit in picture is a simple regulator. I need to add 3.3V output delay-off for about 30ms. The reason for this is the battery can momentarily detached from the its contacts. I want to avoid a reset during this time. Any suggestions?

[image: regulator]

Comment: Is your load current a constant 300mA? If I did the math right, 300mA*4.2V*30ms = 37.8mJ, W=1/2CV^2 -> 2.14mF (not uF!). That's a big capacitor...

Comment: Err, and realistically you'd need a whole lot more than that. How about a second battery?

Comment: Use a power Mosfet on the output & delay can be introduced by a cap @ the gate + on time of mosfet.

Comment: @Rishi The problem isn't the delay, its where does the *energy* come from during that period. As others say either a big capacitor or second battery backup is required.

Comment: I understand that battery detaching will happen during starting as you want to add output delay. If you delay the output reaching the receiver, the reset that might happen in the de-bouncing period can be avoided. I am not sure if my understanding of detachment in the starting is correct.

Comment: @uint128_t, sorry to confuse, 300mA is output current of the regulator. Maximum current should only be around 100mA.

Comment: @Rishi, detachment of battery is not only on starting.

Answer (score 3):

You show dropout voltage of the regulator as 0.1V and the battery voltage is 3.6V minimum, so you have only 0.2V drop allowed at the input.

The minimum required capacitance is Cmin = \$ \frac {t_{HOLDUP}\cdot Iout}{\Delta V}\$

In your case that would be 0.05F (ignoring capacitor resistance). That's a problem. Inexpensive ultracaps tend to have **far** too high internal resistance to be usable (several ohms to tens of ohms). Useful in low current situations, but not here. AVX [makes](http://datasheets.avx.com/BestCap.pdf) a 100mF cap with 80m\$\Omega\$ internal resistance, but it's very expensive (almost $7 in 1,000 quantity).

Perhaps you can solve the problem using out-of-box thinking. I suggest either improving the battery connections or consider detecting an imminent drop-out and using an interrupt to put the circuit in a very low power survival state to ride out the power loss condition, then recover when power is restored. That way you may be able to use a moderately large electrolytic capacitor instead of a ultracap/supercap.

Comment: the schematic seems to already have such a connection `03 master MCU`

Comment: For MCU or memory backup, they sell "backup caps" with a formfactor of a coin cell and rated like a 5V supercap (1F). However I wouldn't use them upstream of the regulator, but to maintain say the Reset and MCU supply to avoid reset. [example product](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_1935422_-1)